# Generate enemies around the player from all directions randomly

Tags: python, pygame

The enemy are being generated from above the screen and then move toward player in the middle, I want to generate enemies randomly around the screen from all directions but not inside the screen directly and proceed to move towards the player and also enemy sprites are sometimes joining combining and moving together how to repel the enemy sprites.

I have tried changing x,y coordinates of enemy objects using a random range but sometimes they generate objects inside the play screen, I want enemies to generate outside the playing window.

```
class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load('enemy.png'), (33, 33))
        self.image_orig = self.image.copy()
        self.radius = int(29 * .80 / 2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speed = 4
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = 5
        self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > 50:
            self.last_update = now
            self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed) % 360
            new_image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.image_orig, self.rot, 1)
            old_center = self.rect.center
            self.image = new_image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = old_center

    def update(self):
        self.rotate()
        dirvect = pg.math.Vector2(rotator.rect.x - self.rect.x,
                                  rotator.rect.y- self.rect.y)
        if dirvect.length_squared() > 0:
            dirvect = dirvect.normalize()

            # Move along this normalized vector towards the player at current speed.
        if dirvect.length_squared() > 0:
            dirvect.scale_to_length(self.speed)
        self.rect.move_ip(dirvect)
        if self.rect.top > height + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > width + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speed = random.randrange(1, 4)
```

[UPDATE]
This the remaining code:

```
import math
import random
import os
import pygame as pg
import sys

pg.init()
height = 650
width = 1200

os_x = 100
os_y = 45
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (os_x, os_y)

screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height), pg.NOFRAME)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
background = pg.image.load('background.png').convert()
background = pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load('background.png'), (width, height))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
running = True

font_name = pg.font.match_font('Bahnschrift', bold=True)


def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y, color):
   [...]


class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
[...]    

class Rotator(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen_rect):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen_rect = screen_rect
        self.master_image = pg.image.load('spaceship.png').convert_alpha()
        self.master_image = pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load('spaceship.png'), (33, 33))
        self.radius = 12
        self.image = self.master_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=[width / 2, height / 2])
        self.delay = 10
        self.timer = 0.0
        self.angle = 0
        self.distance = 0
        self.angle_offset = 0

    def get_angle(self):
        mouse = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        offset = (self.rect.centerx - mouse[0], self.rect.centery - mouse[1])
        self.angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(*offset)) - self.angle_offset
        old_center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.master_image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=old_center)
        self.distance = math.sqrt((offset[0] * offset[0]) + (offset[1] * offset[1]))

    def update(self):
        self.get_angle()
        self.display = 'angle:{:.2f} distance:{:.2f}'.format(self.angle, self.distance)
        self.dx = 1
        self.dy = 1
        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.screen_rect)

    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def shoot(self, mousepos):
        dx = mousepos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        dy = mousepos[1] - self.rect.centery
        if abs(dx) > 0 or abs(dy) > 0:
            bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, dx, dy)
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation about how your entire playing field and the part that is seen by the player are structured. What framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using pycharm

Comment: Pycharm is your Integrated Development Environment. A framework would be a collection of code you are using like [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: PyGame Framework

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your screen is the same size as your game's board. You can only place objects on valid coordinates of course, so if you display the entire board placing enemies outside of your view is impossible.

Comment: if give coordinate in (-100,-40) in self.rect.y = random.randrange() the enemies come from above if (690,750) enemies come from below but this self.rect.y = (random.randrange(), random.randrange())[random.randrange(0,2)]  is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197511/discussion-between-akhil-anand-sirra-and-jaaq).

Comment: My screen size is 1920x1080 not the same size as game window

Comment: I updated my answer again and tried to thoroughly show how to generate random spawn points in the parts of the map not currently displayed to the player. IF you have any other questions not directly related to your question, please start a new one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much informations to go by here, but you probably need to check the x and y range your play window has and make sure the random spawn coordinates you generate are outside of it:

In your init:

```py
# These are just example min/max values. Maybe pass these as arguments to your __init__ method.
min_x = min_y = -1000
max_x = max_y = 1000
min_playwindow_x = min_playwindow_y = 500
max_playwindow_x = max_playwindow_y = 600

self.x = (random.randrange(min_x, min_playwindow_x), random.randrange(max_playwindow_x, max_x))[random.randrange(0,2)]

self.y = (random.randrange(min_y, min_playwindow_y), random.randrange(max_playwindow_y, max_y))[random.randrange(0,2)]
```

This solution should work in basically any setup. For x and y it generates a tuple of values outside the playing window. Then a coinflip decides on the value. This will only spawn mobs that are diagonally outside the playing field, but it will always generate valid random coordinates.

Another approach would be just generating as many random variables as needed to get a valid pair like this:

```py
while min_playingwindow_x <= self.x <= max_playingwindow_x and 
      min_playingwindow_y <= self.y <= max_playingwindow_y:
    # While within screen(undesired) calculate new random positions
    self.x = random.randrange(min_x, max_x)
    self.y = random.randrange(min_y, max_y)
```

This can be really slow however if your valid amount of positions is (for example) only 1% of the total positions.

IF you need something really fleshed out, you need to know the corners of both your map and the rectangle that is actually displayed, which is I assume smaller than the entire map(otherwise you cannot spawn enemies outside your view.

```
(0,0)
+----------------------+
|           A          |
|-----+-----------+----|
|  D  |      W    | B  |
|-----+-----------+----|
|          C           |
+----------------------+(max_x, max_y)
```

In this diagram W is the window that is acutally visible to the player, and A,B,C,D together are the part of your map that is not currently visible. Since you only want to spawn mobs outside the player's view, you'll need to make sure that the coordinates you generate are inside your map and outside your view:

```py
def generate_coordinates_outside_of_view(map_width=1000, map_height=1000, view_window_top_left=(100, 100),
                                         view_width=600, view_height=400):
    """
    A very over the top way to generate coordinates outside surrounding a rectangle within a map almost without bias
    :param map_width: width of map in pixels (note that 0,0 on the map is top left)
    :param map_height: height of map in pixels
    :param view_window_top_left: top left point(2-tuple of ints) of visible part of map
    :param view_width: width of view in pixels
    :param view_height: height of view in pixels
    """
    from random import randrange

    # generate 2 samples for each x and y, one guaranteed to be random, and one outside the view for sure.
    x = (randrange(0, map_width), (randrange(0, view_window_top_left[0]),
          randrange(view_window_top_left[0] + view_width, map_width))[randrange(0, 2)])
    y = (randrange(0, map_height), (randrange(0, view_window_top_left[1]),
          randrange(view_window_top_left[1] + view_height, map_height))[randrange(0, 2)])

    # now we have 4 values. To get a point outside our view we have to return a point where at least 1 of the
    # values x/y is guaranteed to be outside the view.

    if randrange(0, 2) == 1:  # to be almost completely unbiased we randomize the check
        selection_x = randrange(0, 2)
        selection_y = randrange(0, 2) if selection_x == 1 else 1
    else:
        selection_y = randrange(0, 2)
        selection_x = randrange(0, 2) if selection_y == 1 else 1

    return x[selection_x], y[selection_y]
```

HTH

Comment: It is not working my window size if 1200x650 after trying the the enemies are still coming from same place.

Comment: You're probably having a playing window and a border around the playing window that is not visible. What are the dimensions of both the entire playing field and your playing window and at which positions are the corners of your playing window?

Comment: My player is in the middle of the screen facing cursor direction shooting the play window size is 1200x650

Comment: My screen size is 1920x1080 not the same size as game window

Comment: if give coordinate in (-100,-40) in self.rect.y = random.randrange() the enemies come from above if (690,750) enemies come from below but this self.rect.y = (random.randrange(), random.randrange())[random.randrange(0,2)] is not working.

Comment: This code does work: `(randrange(1,10), randrange(20,30))[randrange(0,2)]` just don't forget to `from random import randrange`.